# Nonzero function with zero Taylor series expansions of every order

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose that I define a function $f(x)$=$e^{-1/x^2}$ when x is non zero and 
                                        =$0$ when x is zero.

I found that(by using limit definition of derivative and sandwich-squeezing principle) $f^{n}(x)$=$0$ for all natural nos.

Now  fuction f(x) does have a Taylor series expansion about x=$0$. Then ,why is that when one tries to write power series for $f(x)$,it becomes a zero series which is certainly not equal to $f(x)$?

Comment: Because $f(x)=o(x^n)$ for every $n$. (Note that, contrarily to what you assert, $f$ does have Taylor series expansions at $x=0$.)

Comment: @Did,I asserted  $f$ doesn't have Taylor series expansion about x=$0$

Comment: @Did ,Would you please elaborate your comment ..

Comment: Yes, and $f$ does have Taylor series expansions about $x=0$, only $f$ is not equal to the sum of its Taylor series (which is different from not having a T.s.e.).

Comment: So,why is it happening in this case? All derivatives of f exist so why doesn't it have T.S.E. unlike in complex analysis.

Comment: The short answer is that your function isn't analytic on zero.

Comment: @Kristoffer Ryhi,But derivative of f exists at $x$=$0$.Also, it exists in a nbd around zero(in this case nbd is an interval not a disk though).So, shouldn't $f $be analytic at x=$0$?

Comment: @kilimanjaro analytic and differentiable is only equivalent in the complex plane.

Comment: That's partially truth but anyways I still didn't get my answer.

Comment: There exist  infinitely differentiable real functions that cannot be extended to analytic complex functions. That function is an example. Equivalently the restrictions of analytic functions that map R to R ,to the real domain, does not yield all infinitely differentiable real functions. It yields a class called real-analytic.